# Learn Arduino Basics : Temperature sensor with LCD Display and Potentiometer setup

Tags: temperature-sensor, temperature, breadboard

I have temperature sensor, potentiometer and LCD screen attached to mini breadboard and wired to an Arduino. My temp sensor appears to be working fine however sometimes it reads inaccurate numbers which is unusual. It only does this when I have all my components on the same mini breadboard. When I detach then reattach my temperature sensor to a separate breadboard its hasn't been noticeably inaccurate. There is no issue but I was thinking that maybe the temperature sensor is hotter because its closer other to components or maybe because the close electrical wiring range is making it hotter. My solution is putting the temp gauge on another breadboard but I was save space to use one. Any ideas as why my gauge reads random hotter temperatures more often when sharing a board?

Comment: What temperature sensor do you have?

Comment: what do you mean by `hotter`?

Comment: LM35 temerature sensor. By hotter I mean; when the sensor begins reading inaccurately, the degrees ranges from 5-10 degrees hotter than what it should be.

Answer (score 2):

It could be measuring the heat of nearby components, or it could be a wiring issue. Breadboards are convenient but it also allows people to use poor wiring practices. Long wires, poor ground return paths, insufficient bypass capacitors.

The first thing to do is to arrange the layout so that there is little chance of the other components heating the sensor. You might also try using a fan to blow on all the components. Make it so that if there is any heat generated it does not accumulate it the parts. If that clears up the problem then look into making a better thermal layout. Maybe with the sensor physically separate from the rest of the circuit.

If the fan makes no difference then you may need to consider the way it has been wired.